# Обновление hosts через cmd

Tags: windows, selenium, cmd, hosts

Задача следующая: требуется как-то перезаписывать хосты в файле hosts через cmd.
Либо как-то на время жизни программы активировать свой файл hosts.
Долго гуглил и нашел только как просто тупо добавлять новые записи, такое решение мне не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть [очень приятная и мощная CLI-утилита](http://veg.by/ru/projects/hostscmd/)  (с хорошей русской справкой, если важно), которой можно работать, в том числе, и из CMD.  Рекомендую к использованию. Там всё просто, привожу примеры команд:

```
hosts add <host> <aliases> <addr> # <comment>
#Добавляет новый хост, <addr> по умолчанию 127.0.0.1 
hosts set <host|mask> <addr> # <comment>
#Добавляет хост или обновляет его IP адрес и комментарий 
hosts rem <host|mask>
Удаляет конкретный хост или соответствующие маске
```

и ещё масса полезного.

Ну, а если важно именно из CMD, то что-то вроде:

```
copy %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts.bkp
rem делаем резервную копию - на всякий случай
echo 192.168.0.1 mysite1.com > %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
rem первая запись, все последующие - через >>
echo 192.168.0.2 mysite2.com >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
```

и так далее.. Затем не забыть восстановить старый hosts обратно!